# Scio JobTest, PubSubIO, pubsubSubscriptionWithAttributes, timestampAttribute and Windowing issue

Tags: spotify-scio

I'm building a pipeline to backup data from PubSub into GCS and wanted to create a test using `JobTest` and I'm struggling to get the PubSubIO to properly get the event time.

PubSub is read using `sc.pubsubSubscriptionWithAttributes[String]("path/to/subscription", timestampAttribute = "doc_timestamp")`. After this I apply windowing and send it to a `CustomIO`

The test looks like this:

```scala
JobTest[PubSub2GCS.type]
  .args("--subscription=input", "--targetDir=output")
  .input(PubsubIO[(String, Map[String, String])]("input"), Seq(("Contents", Map[String, String]("doc_timestamp" -> "2001-01-01T09:10:11.332Z"))))
  .output(CustomIO[KV[String, WindowedDoc]]("output"))(_.debug())
  .run()
```

and the result is that the value is placed in the `-290308-12-21T20:00:00.000Z..-290308-12-21T21:00:00.000Z` window!!. Possibly because the date on `"doc_timestamp"` is not properly interpreted. Actually, the window never changes, regardless of the value on `"doc_timestamp"` key.

Luckily the job works fine when running in production, but I'd like to have this tests written.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `Map[String, String]` attributes in `ScioContext#pubsubSubscriptionWithAttributes` are not populated in `JobTest`.

We can probably add a condition here, and set timestamp if `ScioContext#isTest` and `timestampAttribute != null`
https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/master/scio-core/src/main/scala/com/spotify/scio/ScioContext.scala#L572

Seems like a trivia fix. Can you please file an issue [here](https://github.com/spotify/scio/issues) and maybe submit a PR?